# R image of a single color using CIELAB or RGB values

Tags: r, image, colors, rgb, cielab

I wish to generate a plot of a single color based on a value of either CIELAB values or RGB values in R.

I have seen examples of displaying colors in RColorBrewer:

```
library(RColorBrewer)
mypalette<-brewer.pal(7,"Greens")
image(1:7,1,as.matrix(1:7),col=mypalette,xlab="Greens (sequential)",
      ylab="",xaxt="n",yaxt="n",bty="n")
```

However how could I display a single color in image()?

Cheers,

Comment: Use `col="Green"` or any other color that you want. Is that what you meant by single color?

Comment: No I mean by RGB values or LAB values, also how would you show a single color in the plot?